# process.env vs app.get('env') on getting the express.js environment

Tags: node.js, express

So, in my node.js 5.2.0 / express.js 4.2.0 I can do

```
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(//etc
```

or

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
if (env === 'development') {
  app.use(//etc
```

So `process.env.NODE_ENV` and `app.get('env')` both get the environment's value. Is there any significant difference besides the syntax?

Thanks

Comment: There is an already accepted answer of mine, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54770052/warning-node-env-value-of-test-did-not-match-any-deployment-config-file-name/61135173#61135173

By default, `app.get('env')` returns `development` and `process.env.NODE_ENV` returns `undefined`. If you want to set both at the same time and update the environments, you may refer to the above link.

Answer (score 78):

There is no significant difference.

Express `app.get('env')` returns `'development'` if NODE_ENV is not defined. So you don't need the line to test its existence and set default.